# Is it OK to globally set the mybatis executor mode to BATCH?

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am currently developing a Spring Boot app, which uses mybatis for its persistence layer. I want to optimize the batch insertion of entities in the following scenario:

```
// flightSerieMapper and legMapper are used to create a series of flights.
// legMapper needs to use batch insertion.
@Transactional
    public FlightSerie add(FlightSerie flightSerie) {
        Integer flightSerieId = flightSeriesSequenceGenerator.getNext();
        flightSerie.setFlightSerieId(flightSerieId);
        flightSerieMapper.create(flightSerie);
        // create legs in batch mode
        for (Leg leg : flightSerie.getFlightLegs()) {
            Integer flightLegId = flightLegsSequenceGenerator.getNext();
            leg.setLegId(flightLegId);
            legMapper.create(leg);
        }
        return flightSerie;
    }
```

mybatis is configured as follows in `application.properties`:

```
# this can be externalized if necessary
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
mybatis.executor-type=BATCH
```

This means that mybatis will execute all statements in batch mode by default, including single insert/update/delete statements. Is this OK? Are there any issues I should be aware of?

Another approach would be to use a dedicated SQLSession specifically for the LegMapper. Which approach is the best (dedicated SQLSession vs global setting in application.properties)?

*Note*: I have seen other examples where "batch inserts" are created using a `<foreach/>` loop directly in the mybatis xml mapper file. I don't want to use this approach because it does not actually provide a batch insert.

Comment: You have to make sure you do a flush (method with @Flush annotation) for all your inserts and updates.

Comment: Thanks Ian. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

As [@Ian Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970200/ian-lim) said, make sure you annotate mapper methods with inserts and updates with `@Flush` annotation if you globally set executor type to `BATCH`.

> Another approach would be to use a dedicated SQLSession specifically
> for the LegMapper. Which approach is the best (dedicated SQLSession vs
> global setting in application.properties)?

Keep in mind that if you are using different SQL sessions for different mappers there will be different transactions for each SQL session. If a service or service method annotated with `@Transactional` uses several mappers that use different SQL sessions it will allocate different SQL transactions. So it's impossible to do atomic data operation that involves mappers with different SQL sessions.